# What's the correct way to set the time on ESXI hosts?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I tried doing it through cli with the following command:

```
esxcli system time set -d 3 -M 11 -y 2021 -H 14 -m 10 -s 0
```

But after restarting a guest OS (Windows), the time on it resets to the wrong one again (1 hour late in this case).

Comment: Windows guests usually aren't configured to synchronize time with the host.

Comment: Sometimes time-related tools miss the time zone info, or they use it badly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way is to continuously synchronize your host with an SNTP server.

You should always have an exact time on your host to ensure that any guest that is 'stunned' (pause, snapshot, ...) is resynchronized correctly.
If the host's time is off, it'll push that time to any stunned guests (regardless of the *synchronize guest time with host* setting!), potentially causing time to jump. You surely don't want that.

In vSphere Client, go to *Host -> Manage -> System -> Time & Date -> Edit SNTP settings*. Set *NTP service startup policy* to *Start and stop with host* and enter a trusted SNTP server. In *Services* start the *ntpd* service.

For the guest itself you can choose whether you generally want to synchronize with the host or (better) with your trusted SNTP server directly. Most often, Windows clients and servers are synced through AD - either a domain controller or a dedicated SNTP 'master'.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks. Although the path to NTP looks like this on my vSphere Client (version 7.0.2.00400): Host -> Configure -> System -> Time Configuration -> Network Time Protocol -> Edit.

Comment: Yes, that's likely the path with a vCenter connection - my lab VCSA's currently dead, so I connected to the host directly. ;-)